# Display vertical fractional numbers in UILabel or text view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, uilabel, typography

I'm trying to display fractional numbers in an iPhone app, e.g. 12 and 3/81 should be displayed as the number "12" followed by the numerator "3" on top, a horizontal line, and the denominator "81" at the bottom.

I would greatly appreciate if anyone could advise me on how to achieve this. Should I subclass a `UILabel` and do custom drawing of the fraction, or should I subclass a `UITextView`?

Is there any sample code somewhere that shows how such custom drawing of `UILabel` or `UITextView` can be done?

Comment: shang, any chance you have some sample code to share? did you create a custom UIView subclass?

Comment: @shang: did you figure out how to do that ? would be great if you could show the sample code. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `UIView` subclass called FractionView with labels representing the numerator, the denominator and the separator (slash). Create `numerator` and `denominator` properties for the view to store the values you pass and set the labels accordingly. You can then drop this view anywhere you need to display fractions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! But I would like the fraction line to be a variable one. e.g. The fraction line for 1/100000 should be longer than 1/10. Do you think it's possible to dynamically change the length of the fraction line depending on the size of the denominator?

Comment: Sure. Just use the label's `sizeToFit:` to resize accordingly.